# UTC vs. GMT - Java vs. .Net

Tags: java, timezone, utc, gmt

In .Net UTC and GMT are not the same
[Difference between UTC and GMT Standard Time in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292334/difference-between-utc-and-gmt-standard-time-in-net)

Is it the same with Java? 
Does Java has the notion that GMT has DST changes while UTC doesnt?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

[As the documentation explains](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), GMT is equivalent to UT and the difference between UT and UTC is "is an invisibly fine hair to split".

GMT and UTC will never have "Daylight Savings" or "Summer Time" applied to them.

Answer (score 6):

Daylight Saving Time and GMT is different. GMT is GMT, wherever and whenever.

GMT+0 is standard British Time

GMT+1 is BST (British Summer Time)

Answer (score 1):

You're misreading the other question. It's not "UTC vs. GMT", it's "UTC vs. GMT Standard Time".