# Google Calendar generates incorrect time in xml feed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I'm generating an ICS feed from an exchange server with the timezone set to "UTC Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"; I'm then importing this into Google Calendar, which then creates an XML feed which I then import into FullCalendar in my Rails application.

The ICS feed from the exchange server has this:

```
SUMMARY:Test Event
DTSTART;TZID=GMT Standard Time:20140713T000000
DTEND;TZID=GMT Standard Time:20140719T000000
```

However the XML feed generated by Google Calendar, is wrong. it shows:

```
<title type='html'>Y12 Biology Field Trip</title><summary type='html'>When: Sat 12 Jul 2014 23:00 to Fri 18 Jul 2014 23:00&amp;nbsp;
UTC&lt;br&gt;
```

How do I correct the xml feed created by Google Calendar? It appears it isn't using GMT Daylight saving.

Or, how do I force use of Daylight saving in Google Calendar/FullCalendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My 2nd go at this... For me, there is nothing incorrect in the google feed. Google is receiving a time in "GMT Standard Time", an ambiguous time zone which, contrary to what you might expect, [may have daylight saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292334/difference-between-utc-and-gmt-standard-time-in-net). It then converts this time to UTC (no daylight saving), It does this because UTC is the timezone of the google calendar. Events imported into a google calendar are converted to the time zone of the google calendar. So midnight becomes 11pm.

I don't know fullcalendar, but the google xml feed is not suited for digestion by machines. Event times are mixed up in text descriptions. The timezone information is too short to be definitive. You would be much better sticking with Icalendar for exchanging calendar information. Why can't full calendar handle the Ical feed directly from Exchange? If you persist with google xml, try changing the time zone setting on the google calendar.